# Could not load file or assembly for c1webreport1 tool in compnentone studio

Tags: asp.net

I'm using Licensed componentone product in my ASP.NET application and spcefically i use C1WebReport1 control from the product.while upgrading C1WebReport1 control from version 2.5.20072.239 to 2.6.20093.53207,i get the error message as

**"Could not load file or assembly 'C1.Web.C1WebReport.2, Version=2.6.20093.53207, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=594a0605db190bb9' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"**

can any one help me to bring complete solution?

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Omprakash

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the new (version 2.6.20093.53207) dll might not be in your bin folder. You can view the version of the dll by right-clicking, selecting properties and viewing the summary tab. Make sure you have the right version included in your project. If you have an old dll.refresh file I would delete it and also go into design view on the form that uses WebReport to regenerate the licensing files.

By the way, ComponentOne just released a brand new [ReportViewer for ASP.NET](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/ReportViewerASPNET/) you might want to try out too. If you have a license for 2009v3 you probably will qualify for the free upgrade!